# how to exclude other gradle tasks when running checkstyle plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, checkstyle

I hava a springBoot2.x project build with gradle 5.4 and querydsl ,
when I run  `./gradlew clean build` without checkstyle plugin all things go well. 
But when I add checkstyle plugin in `build.gradle`  and run `./gradlew clean build` ,
it came out this error:
`Execution failed for task ':compileQuerydslJava'`,    then I try to run `./gradlew clean build -x compileQuerydslJava` it works again. So my question is : how to  exclude compileQuerydslJava on checkstyle config in build.gradle file?

Comment: Please run your build with command line flag `--info` and `--stacktrace` and post the relevant bits. It might help to understand what is going on.

Comment: seems a bug of gradle plugin , checkstyle could not find class path. same thing like https://github.com/ewerk/gradle-plugins/issues/84, I add checkstyle source set and it works